# The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager - options

Tags: python, tkinter, alignment, tkinter-layout

I am teaching myself TKINTER at the moment. I have written...

```
self.frameBottom = tk.Frame(master)
self.frameBottom.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH)

self.textBox = tk.Text(master, height=1)
self.textBox.pack(side = tk.LEFT, expand=1, fill=tk.X)

self.searchButton = tk.Button(master, text="Search",  command=self.searchButtonPress)
self.searchButton.pack(side = tk.RIGHT)

self.textBoxResults = tk.Text(self.frameBottom)
self.textBoxResults.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

however the lower textBoxResults does not expand in the Y direction to fill the window as can be seen in this [GUI picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aercg.png). How can I make the textBoxResults expand in the Y direction, and keep the textBox and searchButton attached to the top please?

TIA

Comment: Read up on [The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager - options](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)

Comment: Add `expand=1` to `self.frameBottom.pack(...)`.

Comment: Thanks @acw1668, expand=1 worked!

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This is a community-wiky answer, feel free to add related content!</sub>

- [Python Tutorial - 25.1.6.2. The Packer](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.html#the-packer)
- [Python Tutorial - 25.1.6.3. Packer Options](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.html#packer-options)

  - `side=`
    Specifies which side to pack the widget against: `TOP` (default), `LEFT`, `BOTTOM` and `RIGHT`
  - `expand=`
    Boolean, 0 or 1.
  - `fill=`
    Legal values: `'x'`, `'y'`, `'both'`, `'none'`.
  - `ipadx=`
    Internal padding.
- [The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)

  > The Pack geometry manager packs widgets in rows or columns. You can use options like fill, expand, and side to control this geometry manager.