# How can I put the color choosing menu above the chat? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

(tkinter) I'm trying to have the color menu above the chat space. I've tryed changing the side variable with the pack function (eg : .pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)) but never acheived it. Ideally the color menu would be at the top left, the chat in the middle and the entry + button at the bottom.

```
    import tkinter
    import tkinter.scrolledtext

    class Interface(tkinter.Frame):

            def __init__(self, root):
                    tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)
                    self.pack()
                    # The chat where all the texts appears
                    self.chat = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self)
                    self.chat.pack(side="top")
                    self.chat.configure(state='disabled')

                    # The color choosing
                    possible_colors= ["normal", "green", "blue", "red", "yellow", "purple"]
                    self.color= tkinter.StringVar(self)
                    self.color.set(possible_colors[0])
                    self.color_menu= tkinter.OptionMenu(self, self.color, *possible_colors)
                    self.color_menu.pack(side='top')

                    # The entry space for the chat
                    self.entry= tkinter.Entry(self)
                    self.entry.pack(side="left", fill='both', expand='yes')

                   # The send button
                   self.button= tkinter.Button(self, text='send', command=self.function_one)
                   root.bind('<Return>', self.function_one)
                   self.button.pack(side="bottom")

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    interface = Interface(root)
    interface.mainloop()
```

Comment: Call `.color_menu.pack(side='top')` as the first statement, read [The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager - options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60932260/7414759)

Comment: tried it before didn't work but don't know why now it does thanks a lot I'm going to investigate a bit about why.