# Tkiner, The frames are located in the middle

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently making a messenger program. As you can see in the title, i created a frame inside frame using Tkinter and inner frames are automatically vertically aligned. But I don't want this. They always want to start from the top. It's okay when there are a large number of frames inside the frame, but if not, the problem occurs. Of course, this is because I have a lack of understanding of 'Tkinter', but I still ask for your help. I think it's a problem with the '' event of the frames or frames in class List

and apologize korean in code

```py
import tkinter as tk
from inspect import *


memberInfo = [
                (3, 'ukhyun2', '1234', 'Jail', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'jail.png'),
                (4, 'ukhyun', '1234', 'welcome', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'welcome.png'),
                (5, 'ukhyun3', '1234', 'hello', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'hello.png'),
                (6, 'ukhyun', '1234', 'welcome', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'welcome.png'),
                (7, 'ukhyun3', '1234', 'hello', '01024021051', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'hello.png'),
                (8, 'ukhyun', '1234', 'welcome', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'welcome.png'),
                (9, 'ukhyun3', '1234', 'hello', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'hello.png'),
                (10, 'ukhyun', '1234', 'welcome', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'welcome.png'),
                (11, 'ukhyun3', '1234', 'hello', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'hello.png'),
                (12, 'ukhyun', '1234', 'welcome', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'welcome.png'),
                (13, 'ukhyun3', '1234', 'hello', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'hello.png'),
                (14, 'ukhyun', '1234', 'welcome', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'welcome.png'),
                (15, 'ukhyun3', '1234', 'hello', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'hello.png'),
                (16, 'ukhyun', '1234', 'welcome', '01024021051', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'welcome.png'),
                (17, 'ukhyun3', '1234', 'hello', '01024021051', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'hello.png'),
                (18, 'ukhyun', '1234', 'welcome', '01024021051', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'welcome.png'),
                (19, 'ukhyun3', '1234', 'hello', '01012341234', 'hyun4911@gmail.com', 'hello.png')]

class mainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwagrs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwagrs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.config(bg="white")

        staff = staffList(self)


class List(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwagrs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwagrs)
        self.config(bg='red')
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.vScrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.vScrollBar.pack(fill='y', side='right')

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(
            self, bg='blue', bd=0, highlightthickness=0, yscrollcommand=self.vScrollBar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', side='left', expand=True)

        self.vScrollBar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.interior = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bg="black")
        self.interior.pack(fill='both')

        self.interiorId = self.canvas.create_window(
            0, 0, window=self.interior, anchor='nw')

        def _configure_interior(e):
            size = (self.interior.winfo_reqwidth(),
                    self.interior.winfo_reqheight())
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.interior.bbox('all'))
            print(self.canvas.yview)

            if self.interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                self.canvas.config(width=self.interior.winfo_reqwidth())
        self.interior.bind("<Configure>", _configure_interior)

        def _configure_canvas(e):
            if self.interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                self.canvas.itemconfigure(
                    self.interiorId, width=self.canvas.winfo_width())
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", _configure_canvas)

        def _wheel(e):
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(round(-1*(e.delta/120)), 'units')
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _wheel)

        for i in getmembers(self.canvas.yview):
            print(i)
        print(self.canvas.yview)


class staffList(List):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        List.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.users = []
        self.imgs = []
        for i in range(3):
            self.users.append(tk.Frame(self.interior, bd=0, bg='red'))
            self.users[-1].pack(side='top', fill='x')

            tk.Label(self.users[-1], text="hello").pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Messenger - GoodAuction")
    root.minsize(400, 500)
    root.geometry('400x600+200+200')
    root.iconbitmap(default=r"./img/favicon.ico")

    app = mainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That was a lot of code, much of which does not relate to tkinter. Can you please try to minimize the code to make it easier to assist you :)

Comment: Sorry reader, I edit my code on post

Comment: I think `self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.interior.bbox('all'))` should be `self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))` instead.  The space above those labels (the blue region) is due to that the scrollregion is smaller than the viewable area.  If you put more labels, for example 30 labels, you will see the difference.

Comment: Read up on [the-tkinter-pack-geometry-manager-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60931313)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I have understood correctly but see if this is right; 
You have three labels packed vertically:

```
hello
hello
hello
```

but want them hoizontally:

```
hello hello hello
```

In that case; in the calss `staffList()` you pack them explicitly vertically:

```
self.users[-1].pack(side='top', fill='x')
                           ^
packs vertically ----------|
```

but you can change it to:

```
self.users[-1].pack(side='left', fill='x')
                           ^
packs to the left----------|
```

or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Thank you for answering first! It's a little different from what I want. Perhaps my explanation is lacking. 

raise the mouse wheel and you will see meaningless space above the label. I want to get rid of this space and put a label on top.

Comment: Looked again and I cant find the thing that screws up the scrollregion. But then again, I don't really understand your implementation.