# How to add padding before element name in tkinter listbox or remove underline under selected item?

Tags: python, tkinter

When inserting elements in listbox I want to add a little padding to their right. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
listbox = Listbox(root,width = 50)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
for ele in range(1,10):
    listbox.insert(END,str(ele))

root.mainloop()
```

Gives:

[image]

I want something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
listbox = Listbox(root,width = 50)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
for ele in range(1,10):
    listbox.insert(END,"      "+str(ele))

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Now, I am looking for an in-build way of doing this because I need add extra code to remove those spaces when I do `listbox.get(listbox.curselection())`. Or for a way to remove the underline under the selected item so that the user can't see my dirty quick fix.

Comment: To remove the underline, set `activestyle='none'` when creating the listbox.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you very much... it works :-).. I have been searching for it for soo long... can you please suggest some place (like a site or something) where I can find these options...

Comment: You can go through [effbot.org](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm), where you can see all the configuration options of every widget and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your `Listbox` in a `Frame` with `ipadx`.
LiveDemo: [reply.it](https://repl.it/repls/DarkSwiftNasm)

**Reference**

- [The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager - options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60932260/7414759)

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('600x300+50+50')
        self.configure(bg='blue')

        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='white')
        frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, ipadx=10)
        listbox = tk.Listbox(frame, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg=frame.cget('bg'), width=50)
        listbox.pack(fill=tk.Y)

        for ele in range(1,10):
            listbox.insert(tk.END, str(ele))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```