# Positioning buttons and entry in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

To begin with, I'm new to this but I've been experimenting with different things.

I set my canvas size to 500 by 500 but Its going above that due to the buttons and entry positions (I think). How would I position both my buttons and my entry on the top of the canvas?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

w = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
w.pack()

textInput = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=2)
textInput.pack()
textInput.get()


def myClick():
    myLabel = Label(root, text=textInput.get())
    myLabel.pack()


def shutDown():
    exitProgram = exit()
    exitProgram.pack()


myButton = Button(root, text="Start", command=myClick)
myButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20, pady=25)
myButton2 = Button(root, text="Stop", command=shutDown)
myButton2.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20, pady=25)

mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60932260/7414759)

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am not sure why you would set the screen size like that, but if I may suggest a better way of doing it, I usually set the canvas size right on the root instance like this :

```py
root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x100") // Whatever size you want
```

and to position the elements in the screen, you have three main options,

> `pack()` - organizes widgets in blocks before placing them in the parent widget.
>
> `grid()` - organizes widgets in a table-like structure in the parent widget.
>
> `place()` - organizes widgets by placing them in a specific position in the parent widget, with this option you can set the elements to a specific x and y in screen.

```py
element.place(x=10, y=10)
element.grid(row=2, column=2)
element.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify where you want to place widgets when you create them.

```py
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

w = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
w.pack()


textInput = Entry(w, width=50, borderwidth=2)  # w, instead of root
textInput.pack()


def myClick():
    myLabel = Label(root, text=textInput.get())
    myLabel.pack()


def shutDown():
    exitProgram = exit()
    exitProgram.pack()


myButton = Button(w, text="Start", command=myClick)  # w, instead of root
myButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20, pady=25)
myButton2 = Button(w, text="Stop", command=shutDown)  # w, instead of root
myButton2.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20, pady=25)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Looks perfect. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the canvas size using the `Tk().geometry` function:

```py
root = Tk()
length = 100, width = 100 #Set the length and the width
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(length, width)) #Whatever size you want
```

You can place an element using:

```py
elem.place(x = 1, y = 1) #places element by (x, y) value, has very few options and is not commonly used
elem.pack() #Moves element to the next available row
elem.grid(row = 0, column = 0) #Places elements in a grid format, with 'row' and 'column' starting at 0, has multiple other options and is most common

'''
elem.grid(row = row, column = column) is recommended
plain running elem.grid() with no row or column is the same as elem.pack()
'''
```

Comment: while elem.grid is the most commonly used, elem.place should work fine for your case, although I would still use elem.grid