# How to make multiple text widgets expand to fill frame in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have code that looks something like this

```
    frame = tk.Frame(self.root.canvas)
    frame.place(x = coords.x, y = coords.y, width = frameWidth*3, height = frameHeight)
    tk.Text(frame).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    tk.Text(frame).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    tk.Text(frame).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

I would like for each of the text boxes to have width frameWidth, but for some reason they are expanding to fill the entire frame. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is the case?

Comment: It is not recommended to use `pack()/grid()/place()` on widgets inside `Canvas`.  Use `Canvas.create_window()` instead.  Also try using `place()` on the `Text` widgets instead of `pack()`.

Comment: Read up on [The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60932260/7414759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since figured out a solution for dynamic textbox size in tkinter. What you need to do is to wrap each text widget with a frame and set the pack_propagate (or grid_propagate) of the frame to 0; the textbox will then expand the fill the frame and will have dynamic sizing the same way a frame would.

Example:

```
frame = tk.Frame(root)
for textBox in boxes:
        textWrap = tk.Frame(frame)
        textWrap.pack_propagate(0)
        textWrap.pack(expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)
        textBox = tk.Text(textWrap)

frame.place(x = coords.x, y = coords.y, width = width, height = height)
```

Because the default pack side is top, this will create three vertically stacked text boxes of width frame.width and of height frame.height/3. This is convenient because it allows you to deal with text box sizes in terms of pixels instead of text units, and if the bounding frame is resized the text boxes are automatically resized as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following attribute for the text widget,

> width-The width of the widget in characters (not pixels!), measured
> according to the current font size.

If you use this method there will have to be some hard coding to get the width right.You can create the Text widget like this.

```
    tk.Text(frame,width=100).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

Comment: You don't have to guess at a hard-coded width, there are other solutions. As written, this answer is misleading because it gives the impression that this is the only solution.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I'm sorry if my answer looked misleading the way it was written.I changed the wording to make it clear the way I can and I have  given the best method I could think of based on the OP's details.Would really appreciate if you could add a better answer as it would help both me and the OP to learn something new.